# C# reading int from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Having problem reading a value from my table in mysql, is the index value i cant read the value back no matter what. all i get is the initialized value of 0 i dont get any error because it return 0, if i run the query in the database it get the correct value. i tried to use executeScalar() but with the same result .

```
     MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    ulong ukey=0;
            try
            {
                string sql_users2 = "SELECT `key` FROM `permuser` WHERE `user` = '" + myuser + "' AND `code` = '" + mycode + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmdSel2 = new MySqlCommand(sql_users2, conn);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmdSel2.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();

                    ukey = dr2.GetUInt64(dr2.GetOrdinal("key")); 
                   // MessageBox.Show("Sorry " + myuser + " already have access to " + mycode + ",\nIf this is an extension, search for the user which key is  " + ukey + "   and edit the end date.", "Duplicate User Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                dr2.Close();
                dr2.Dispose();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex) //catch 2
            {

                MessageBox.Show("catch ukey\nCan't connect to database\n" + ex.ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: What's the error?  What value do you get from the reader?

Comment: define "can't read the value back": what comes back ? any error ? can you append a real-life example (i.e. "if data is like this, code should return an apple, but instead returns a banana") ?

Comment: I assume that you've used the debugger, what was the result? Btw, use [parameters](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlParameter.html)!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a single value from your query, so you could use directly [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of ExecuteReader. (the link point to the description for SqlServer, but it is the same for MySql)

An important question to never forget is the usage of parameters instead of string concatenation.
What happen if your `myuser` or `mycode` variables contain a single quote? You get wrong results or syntax errors. 
Of course, the main problem is the [Sql Injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/) to never understimate.

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
{
    ulong ukey=0;
    try
    {
        string sql_users2 = "SELECT `key` FROM `permuser` WHERE `user` = @usr AND `code` = @code";
        MySqlCommand cmdSel2 = new MySqlCommand(sql_users2, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmdSel2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", myuser);
        cmdSel2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", mycode);

        object result  = cmdSel2.ExecuteScalar();
        if(result != null)
            ukey = Convert.ToUInt64(result); 


    }
    catch (MySqlException ex) //catch 2
    {
        MessageBox.Show("catch ukey\nCan't connect to database\n" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

also I am a bit perplexed about your usage of UInt64. What kind of datatype is stored in the `key` column?

Comment: about the UInt64, I was also because it doesnt make any sense but someone told to tried that and sometimes you get to the point of trying anything no matter what it is...

Comment: Well, but what datatype is column `key`? The conversion could fail or simply give wrong results.

Comment: Do you have negative numbers? It should not be like that with auto-increment, but I'll ask the same because if you try to convert a negative integer value to an UInt64 you get errors. [Try this sample with LinqPAD](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Development/ConvertToUInt64Int32converts32bitsignedintegerto64bitunsignedinteger.htm). Try to use a normal int for ukey and Convert.ToInt32(result);. Also could you update your question with the exact error message (ex.ToString())?

Comment: Sorry, I have read your update now. The result from ExecuteScalar is null or is zero? If it is null, are you sure to connect to the correct database?

Comment: thats the problem i dotn get any error, I just get 0 as a value !

Comment: is zero as the initialized value, is the correct DB cause is the same connection string for all my inserts and reading

Comment: Last try. In your original code you set the parameters for the field user and the field code as string (wrapping in single quotes). Are these fields really of char/text datatype?

Answer (score 0):

way is many simply:

```
ukey = (uint)dr2[0];
```